# How to extend mesh at the edge of a photogrammetry model

Tags: sculpting, photogrammetry

I am trying to extend the edges of a model created using photogrammetry in blender. The object is captured well, but the ground it sits on only extends a few feet from the object. I would like the object to have a nice square base of ground, even if the resulting geometry is only an approximation of reality.

I have tried a couple things so far, starting with the most successful:

1. Creating a plane, subdividing it until it matches roughly the mesh density of the ground, manually sculpting the resulting plane to match the edges of the model, then using a Boolean modifier to join. The resulting model is then remeshed to improve geometry. This works, but is very labor intensive.
2. Selecting the edge loop, and scaling it up until it exceeds the dimensions of the square that I am using. Then using dyntopo to increase the density of that mesh, and sculpting it until it is similar to the current mesh of the ground. This is much faster, but the results are somewhat unconvincing.

Does anyone have any ideas? Ideally, I would like to smoothly extend the edge of this model to meet the edges of a second square plane. The major problem I am having is that the transition between the existing model and the artificial extension is quite obvious. Blending that area is hard.

Here's an image showing the geometry I'm trying to extend:

[image]

Here is an example of method 1 in action. If I could achieve this kind of result without so much effort, I would be very happy:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any other than you listed ... only to wait for proper AI feature ...